# Simultaneously visit solutions to two or more backtrackable predicates

Tags: prolog

If I had two predicates that generate values in a sequence, for example:

```
between(1, 3, X), sub_atom(abc, _, 1, _, Y)
```

How can I iterate through them so that I get the solutions:

```
X = 1, Y = a ;
X = 2, Y = b ;
X = 3, Y = c.
```

Trying the normal way of course doesn't work:

```
?- between(1, 3, X), sub_atom(abc, _, 1, _, Y).
X = 1, Y = a ;
X = 1, Y = b ;
X = 1, Y = c ;
X = 2, Y = a ;
```

Of course I can collect the two in lists separately:

```
?- findall(X, between(1, 3, X), Xs), findall(Y, sub_atom(abc, _, 1, _, Y), Ys).
Xs = [1, 2, 3],
Ys = [a, b, c].
```

but this is what I want to avoid. I don't want to make the full list, maybe it is too big. Or maybe I want to use something like `between(1, inf, X)` as one of the generators.

---

There seems to be a solution for something similar called `merge` and outlined here: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=engine-examples but it does something different.

Comment: If your Prolog has [Delimited continuations](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=delcont) (also described as "coroutines" in other places), you can have a master predicate that calls the two generating predicates in turn.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer I was not able to figure those out previously. Can you show how this would roughly go?

Comment: `call_nth(A_0, N), call_nth(B_0, N)` Not that this is as efficient as you probably expect it to be.

Comment: @false This is going to get all solutions up to the Nth every time for `B_0`, right?

Comment: @TA_intern: Internally, yes.

Comment: This may take a bit, I have the (Prolog-specific) "impedance mismatch" between delimited continuations and failure-driven loops in the subroutine; it is not possible to properly "shift back" to a "master" coroutine that tail-calls from failure-driven loop of a "slave" coroutine, because backtracking does exactly what it should: one exits from an old reset/3 on the stack. Maybe I will find a solution still. I need to make the master coroutine also failure-driven... "Engines" suddenly look approriate...

Comment: No, it doesn't seem possible with delimited continuations .  One would need to make `between/3` for example generate solutions in a tail-call loop, going "forward" (never backtracking) from one `yield/1` call to the next `yield/1` call in a new stack frame, but there is no standard way to "package" the state of the `between/3` predicate so that it can be passed around. One needs a special continuation-friendly `between_yielding/3` which internally calls `yield/1` for every new solution. But this is really something that [engines](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=engines) are for.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Yes see the answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that it is possible to simultaneously visit solutions to two backtrackable predicates using **engines**.

```
simultaneously_visit_generators(G1, G2, X-Y) :-
   engine_create(X, G1, E1),
   engine_create(Y, G2, E2),
   simultaneously_visit_engines(E1, E2, X-Y).

simultaneously_visit_engines(E1, E2, X-Y) :-
   (   engine_next(E1, X),
       engine_next(E2, Y)
   ->  true
   ;   !,
       fail ).

simultaneously_visit_engines(E1, E2, X-Y) :-
   simultaneously_visit_engines(E1, E2, X-Y).
```

Here are some examples:

```
?- simultaneously_visit_generators(between(1,3,X), sub_atom(abc,_,1,_,Y), X-Y).
X = 1,
Y = a ;
X = 2,
Y = b ;
X = 3,
Y = c ;
false.

?- simultaneously_visit_generators(between(1,inf,X), member(Y,[a,b,c]), X-Y).
X = 1,
Y = a ;
X = 2,
Y = b ;
X = 3,
Y = c ;
false.

?- simultaneously_visit_generators(between(1,2,X), between(1,inf,Y), X-Y).
X = Y, Y = 1 ;
X = Y, Y = 2 ;
false.
```

**TIME COMPLEXITY**

To see that the time complexity is *O*(*n*), consider the following predicate:

```
running_time :-
   forall( between(16, 20, Exponent),
           ( N is 2**Exponent,
             time(findall(X-Y,
                          simultaneously_visit_generators(between(1, inf, X),
                                                          between(1, N, Y), X-Y), _L)))).
```

Empirical results (SWI-Prolog, version 8.2.4):

```
?- running_time.
% 262,162 inferences, 0.063 CPU in 0.078 seconds (80% CPU, 4194592 Lips)
% 524,306 inferences, 0.125 CPU in 0.125 seconds (100% CPU, 4194448 Lips)
% 1,048,594 inferences, 0.297 CPU in 0.297 seconds (100% CPU, 3532106 Lips)
% 2,097,170 inferences, 0.531 CPU in 0.547 seconds (97% CPU, 3947614 Lips)
% 4,194,322 inferences, 1.094 CPU in 1.109 seconds (99% CPU, 3834809 Lips)
true.
```

As we can observe, when the number of answers doubles, time doubles as well.

Comment: Thank you, this is an answer that works for SWI-Prolog.

Comment: I'm confused by the second clause of `simultaneously_visit_engines` which just repeats its head in the body. What is it good for?

Comment: @ThomasH Since `engine_next/2` is semidet (succeeds only once or fails at each call), the second clause of `simultaneously_visit_engines/3` is needed to iterate over all pair of items that can be produced by the engines.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @slago is the solution for SWI-Prolog. I have now defined the following predicate (which also is SWI-Prolog specific):

```
:- meta_predicate zip(?,0, ?,0, -, -).

zip(T1, G1, T2, G2, A1, A2) :-
    engine_create(T1, G1, E1),
    engine_create(T2, G2, E2),
    repeat,
        (   engine_next(E1, A1),
            engine_next(E2, A2)
        ->  true
        ;   !, fail
        ).
```

It works as the other answer:

```
?- zip(X, between(1, inf, X), Y, sub_atom(abc, _, 1, _, Y), A, B).
A = 1,
B = a ;
A = 2,
B = b ;
A = 3,
B = c ;
false.
```

Comment: so is this also SWI-Prolog specific?

Comment: @WillNess yes it is. I would still like to know if there is an obvious way to do that in Prolog.

Comment: this is all very interesting. it means that `zip` must be a _primitive_ in Prolog!

Comment: @WillNess to me it simply means that basic Prolog does not have a mechanism for achieving this other than collecting the solutions to a list.

Comment: yeah that's the same thing put in different words. :)